# How to map DEVPROPKEY to the corresponding human readable form?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm using [SetupDiGetDevicePropertyKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551965(v=vs.85).aspx) to get an array of properties (of type [DEVPROPKEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543544(v=vs.85).aspx)) that are set for a device instance. Is there a way to know a human readable form of a DEVPROPKEY? In other words, how do I translate a DEVPROPKEY structure with

```
fmtid = {a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0}
pid   = 10
```

to (let's say) "Class Guid"?

This is how the property would show up under Device Manager :

[image]

Comment: call [`SetupDiGetDeviceProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551963(v=vs.85).aspx) with `PropertyKey`

Comment: That gives me value (i.e. {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}
) of that property but I want to know what the propertykey (i.e. Class Guid) is

Comment: look in `devpkey.h` for definitions. all this values is well known constant. say your case - `DEVPKEY_Device_ClassGuid`

Comment: i look how `devmgr.dll` do this in `CDeviceDetailsPage::OnInitDialog` - manually map `DEVPROPKEY` to string (load from resource in `System32\en-US\devmgr.dll.mui`) - so no any api for map to string

Comment: @RbMm : Thanks, if you could add that as an answer I'll accept it and close this question